# Location Awareness: Notification when near Coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps

I have an array of multiple coordinates that I am using for annotations. I am trying to make a feature so when someone is driving and they are within 1,000m of any of the points an alert with pop up on the phone(something like a local notification if the apps running in the background) saying, "You are near %@"

Looking for the best approach,

Thanks in advance

Comment: The concept you are looking for is *geofencing*.  If you search for that keyword you will find many tutorials and examples of how to achieve this with CoreLocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Monitoring Shape Based Region](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13) in the *Location Awareness Programming Guide.*

```
- (BOOL)registerRegionWithCircularOverlay:(MKCircle*)overlay andIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier
{
   // Do not create regions if support is unavailable or disabled
   if ( ![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable])
      return NO;

   // Check the authorization status
   if (([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) &&
      ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined))
      return NO;

   // Clear out any old regions to prevent buildup.
   if ([self.locManager.monitoredRegions count] > 0) {
      for (id obj in self.locManager.monitoredRegions)
         [self.locManager stopMonitoringForRegion:obj];
   }

   // If the overlay's radius is too large, registration fails automatically,
   // so clamp the radius to the max value.
   CLLocationDegrees radius = overlay.radius;
   if (radius > self.locManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance) {
      radius = self.locManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
   }

   // Create the region to be monitored.
   CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:overlay.coordinate
                         radius:radius identifier:identifier];
   [self.locManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hey Rob, Im working with CoreLocation and I'm getting my current location also I'm registering my region with this code- (BOOL)registerRegionWithCircularOverlay:(MKCircle*)overlay andIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier{} , wanted to know when does this method gets called????